# Redirect on click to the codeigniter controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to redirect a user to a page when he clicks a div. I wanted to know how doI redirect the user to the CI's new controller from the html view?

Thank YOu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code in your html view,

```
$(function(){
 $('#div_id').on('click',function(){
    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('new_controller'); ?>";
 });
});
```

Do change the `div_id` and `new_controller` to suit your need.